# How to perform a multiple non linear regression without knowing the functions for each variable and the constraints for their coeffcients?

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I have a data for number of cars and its causal variables are identified as GDP, population, urban fraction and fuel price but they have non-linear positive correlation but I don't know what that is. I want to predict the number of cars in future.

Comment: Can you post some data here? Some plots?

Comment: A simple linear regression is giving negative coeffs. for all the variables. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DJ85k_5Z3IArHlHYS7WjGvGFCTx9C6cG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is not easy, you may be better off using a different model, which makes no assumptions on linearity, in contrast to linear regression.